# AWS CentOS SELinux Freezing System

Tags: amazon-web-services, centos, selinux

I am setting up a new CentOS instance on AWS EC2, whenever I disable the SELinux, my system freezes with the following error -

Failed to load SELinux policy, freezing.

I disable the SELinux by editing the config file and appending disabled.

Can you please tell me how can I permanently disable the SELinux without freezing the instance on AWS.

Thanks

Comment: I am editing the file - /etc/sysconfig/selinux, after reboot, it freezes

Comment: what does the system log say?  See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-console.html#instance-console-console-output

Comment: when i edit the selinux file and hit reboot, i am unable to access the system, when i see the event logs from aws, i get this error printed on the screen - Failed to load SELinux policy, freezing.

Comment: i would guess that the way in which you are editing your selinux config file is corrupting the file.  Or maybe I have misled you with "disable" instead of "disabled".  See updates to answer

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file /etc/selinux/config and change this line to exactly this value

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

(note 1. this is not /etc/sysconfig/selinux, one *should* be a link to the other but as your system isn't playing along... 2. I previously said "disable" and not "disabled" sorry )
Then reboot

See https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/sec-sel-enable-disable.html

To eliminate file corruption, try this

perl -p -i -e 's/^SELINUX=(\S+)/SELINUX=disabled/' /etc/selinux/config

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try these commands?

```
/usr/bin/sudo sed -i "s/SELINUX=.*/SELINUX=disabled/g" /etc/selinux/config
/usr/bin/sudo reboot
```

Comment: How would you do this when the AWS EC2 is frozen?